# Subtracting Dynamic columns

Tags: dynamic

I have a data base where I have a new week's data coming in each week. I want to be able to take the values in that field and subtract them with an older week's field to get somewhat of a slope. I need to make this as automated as possible:

Currently have

Recent Decrease: [Week 13] - [Week 9]

I have to go in and change the weeks manually every week, so any suggestions on how to make this less manual?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating two views based on your data - V_CURRENT containing the data of the current week, V_PREVIOUS containing the data of the last week.

Then, you can just do a MINUS / UNION ALL /JOIN with these two views to obtain the data you want.

To only get the data for the current and previous week in your views, you'll have to check how to get the "week of year" in your RDBMS, e.g. for Oracle:

```
select to_char(my_date_field, 'ww') from dual
```